# Windows 8 Metro Style Clipboard Exception

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, clipboard

I have developed an application which reads clipboard data in `DispatcherTimer Tick()` method.
Every second the clipboard data is read.

The application throws no exception in development machine (in debug or relase mode), however if I publish the application on a Win RT Tablet device, I have an exception while reading clipboard, but strangely only in "snap view" mode.

in full view mode, it works without any problem.

The exception is:

```
"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".
```

The code looks like;

```
private async Task Populate()
{
    try
    {

        var clipboardText = await this.GetTextFromClipboard();
           .....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.HandleException("Error occured while reading clipboard: ", ex);
    }
 }


private async Task<string> GetTextFromClipboard()
{
    var dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent(); // Exception occurs here!!!
    if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        var clipboardText = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
        return clipboardText;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

What is wrong here and why it happens only at Snap View mode?

Comment: I found the reason of the problem. The application lost its focus in snapview mode while copying something into clipboard. That means,
Clipboard.GetContent() is only works in foreground.

How can I take the application in foreground before the clipboard data is read in dispatcher timer?

Comment: You can't. Applications are not allowed to steal foreground.

Comment: It should be a way to do that. I need to do this only in snap view mode. A Timer is working to read to clipboard data. Before reading the clipboard data, may be I can take the application on foreground in code. May be setfocus or something like that.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean when you say "There should be a way to do that." Are you saying "A way to do this exists, and I cannot find it"? Or are you saying "Windows should be redesigned so that focus-stealing is possible"?

Comment: Please don't use timer polling to monitor the clipboard.  That strategy is doomed.  Use the appropriate clipboard notification API.  Windows has had it for more than 20 years.

Comment: You are right Chris. It was a wrong strategy and the correct way is to use Clipboard.ContentChanged event.. I will change the implementation in application.